# Quais são as diferenças entre os seletores find() e eq()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou realizando alguns testes para entender qual é a diferença do uso simples de um seletor `eq()` e `find()`, para poder selecionar a primeira linha de uma tabela por exemplo.

**Exemplo 1:**

```
$('table tbody tr:first') // ok

$('table tbody tr').find(':first'); // errado - pega todos os elementos da tr

$('table tbody').find('tr:first'); // ok
```

Nesses 3 testes percebi que para o `find()` funcionar é necessário o mesmo estar acompanhado com uma tag, se eu quero criar uma variável  e armazenar esse seletor, como poderei acessar os objetos desse elemento pelo seletor `find()`?

**Exemplo 2:**

```
var $tab = $('table tbody tr');
$tab.find(':first'); // errado, fica no mesmo jeito do exemplo acima.
```

Detalhe, descobri que pode ser acessado por `eq()`:

**Exemplo 3:**

```
$tab.eq('0'); // ok
```

O exemplo 3 resolve o meu problema, mas tem alguma forma de faze-lo funcionar utilizando o exemplo 2?

Quais são as diferenças do seletor `eq()` e `find()` , além de saber que `eq()` deve ser informado o index exato onde esta a informação e o `find()` procura por um item correspondente?

Pela lógica de como elas funcionam parece que `eq()` possui maior desempenho, não que seja algo significativo diante do processo, mas existe muita diferença ?

Comment: Por que eu recebi -1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esses dois métodos fazem coisas diferentes.

O `.eq()` seleciona elementos dentro de uma coleção, o `.find()` seleciona elementos nos filhos de elementos de uma coleção.

Ou seja um procura em elementos já selecionados (horizontalmente) e o outro na descendencia (transversalmente).

Pode exemplo:

```
<div>
    <p>Div A</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Div B</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Div C</p>
</div>
```

e no jQuery:

```
var divs = $('div');
```

via `.eq()` é possivel selecionar uma das `<div>` mas não a descendência.
via `.find()` é possivel selecionar os elementos `<p>` mas não uma `<div>`.

Combinando os dois seria por exemplo:

```
var divB = $('div').eq(1).find('p').html(); // Div B
```

Comment: Acho que é a resposta correta, sobre o problema dos resultados inesperados. Melhorei a resposta e corrigi o detalhe mencionado. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Em uma curta resposta, existem muitas maneiras de se fazer uma mesma tarefa, basicamente a diferença é que:

- `eq()` usa o numero de index do vetor da seleção.
- `filter()` filtra os itens da seleção
- `find()` usa um sub-seletor pra filtrar (busca os elementos filhos).

O motivo disto é que tem momentos que você poderá usar um loop `for` ou `while` pra trabalhar a sua maneira o `eq`, no entanto se existir um seletor (ou combinação de seletores) que façam o serviço então deves usar `.filter` e então `eq` pode ser dispensável.

Usara apenas `find` quando for buscar os nodes "filhos" e "netos".

O mais importante é que existem muitas maneiras de se fazer uma mesma tarefa, isto é uma característica da programação, vai depender de onde e quando você vai usar e cada função será usada em uma necessidade especifica.

### Sobre desempenho

Provavelmente `eq()` tem melhor performance, mas quando você trabalhar o teu `loop` pra extrair apenas o que interessar então o tempo gasto no final talvez seja o mesmo, a performance varia muito de *onde*, *como* e *quando* você vai usar, por exemplo a estrutura do html pode afetar por exemplo, a única maneira de ter certeza é você fazendo os testes.

### Como testar a performance

Existem algumas ferramentas online um exemplo é o https://jsperf.com, eu pessoalmente já usei, segue um exemplo:

- http://jsperf.com/bitcheck-vs-arithmetic-odd-and-even

Comment: http://jsperf.com/eq-vs-find

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues como eu disse vai da necessidade, no exemplo que postou você usou `for` com `find` o que é desnecessário e o que claramente irá deixar mais lento, já que usamos o `find` pra ser mais específicos e o `.eq` quando necessitamos nós mesmos pegarmos algo que seletores não são capazes.